# Switching from FTP to GIT for deployment

Tags: git, web-deployment

I have being developing web application for well over 4 years now, and am used to the regular workflow of

- Build on local machine
- FTP to live server
- Make changes and FTP again to the live server

This pattern is becoming a bit of a pain, because I sometime forgot the files I worked on.
I've been seeing alot about using GIT for deployment. I've used basic GIT with GitHub; commiting and cloning.
Am a bit lost as to how to use GIT for deployment.
I currently have access to a centos VPS server which am using for my current project.
How i can incorporate GIT into my workflow to make deployment a bit painless.
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Git is a versioning tool - not a deployment tool. There are conventions in Git which support good deployment practices, such using the master branch for maintaining live code, but it is purpose is to provide source control for your code. Pushing code into production (or any environment) requires different tools.

You can look at tools such as WebDeploy or Rake if you are looking to automate your deployments. These are completely separate from git.

If you are looking to reduce the number of steps in your deployment having switched to git, you could look at AppHarbor. All that is required to deploy your code is a 'push' to the AH repository.

Answer (score 0):

If You are using maven to maintain your project Then it is very easy to do.
You can use maven deploy plugin, 
You need include Server to which you want to deploy, By including server in Setting.xml.
This will authenticate user to server

```
 <settings>
  ...
  <servers>
    <server>
      <id>ftp-repository</id>
      <username>user</username>
      <password>pass</password>
    </server>
  </servers>
  ...
</settings>
```

Then finally need to create distribution which links to Server in Setting.xml and Transport plugin for sending artifact to remote server. For example

```
<project>
  ...
  <distributionManagement>
    <repository>
      <id>ftp-repository</id>
      <url>ftp://repository.mycompany.com/repository</url>
    </repository>
  </distributionManagement>

  <build>
    <extensions>
      <!-- Enabling the use of FTP -->
      <extension>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.wagon</groupId>
         <artifactId>wagon-ftp</artifactId>
         <version>1.0-beta-6</version>
      </extension>
    </extensions>
  </build>
  ...
</project>
```

Then good to go by command `mvn deploy`

For more you can have look [maven deploy](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-deploy-plugin/examples/deploy-ftp.html)

Answer (score 0):

Check out this article: http://joemaller.com/990/a-web-focused-git-workflow/

I use this workflow 24/7 as a web developer (have been using it for about 2 months now), no issues whatsoever.

Permissions are maintained.